# Custom Filter for ng-table for a column with two or more properties

Tags: html, filter, angularjs-directive, ngtable

I have two properties in a single column and i want a search filter two search with both the properties. Can anyone of you help me. I am new to Angular JS. Can it be achieved by a custom filter ?. If it is, then how ?. I want to do this search in ng tables default search filter. I want to search two properties in a single input box not in two input boxes.

Comment: Got a solution for this which is as follows. On a success, response create a variable of an array type and store the multiple values in that array variable and push this variable in your success response. Then just filter the data with that new variable. This worked for me.